# How to find RelWithDebInfo or MinSizeRel libraries with CMake?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to link my project to a external library that I also developed in which also also use CMake to build. When I try to find RelWithDebInfo or MinSizeRel like this:

```
FIND_LIBRARY(PCM_LIBRARY_DEBUG pcm
    PATHS   @CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY@
            @CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY@/Debug
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)
FIND_LIBRARY(PCM_LIBRARY_RELEASE pcm
    PATHS   @CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY@
            @CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY@/Release
            @CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY@/MinSizeRel
            @CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY@/RelWithDebInfo
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)

SET(PCM_LIBRARIES debug ${PCM_LIBRARY_DEBUG} optimized ${PCM_LIBRARY_RELEASE})
```

It does not search in ather directories that are not Release or Debug. I also tried creating PCM_LIBRARY_RELWITHDEBINFO and PCM_LIBRARY_MINSIZEREL but the same thing happens because there is only debug and optimized prefixes in SET. Anyone knows how can I link the correct libraries?

Comment: https://github.com/forexample/package-example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is unfortunately one of the shortcomings of using `find_library`. There is no easy way around this without introducing tons of boilerplate code.

The problem here is that when passing files as dependencies to [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html), you can only distinguish between `debug` and `optimized`. If you need more fine-grained control, you will have to manipulate the respective target properties like [`LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES_CONFIG.html) directly. This is not only quite cumbersome, it also requires detailed knowledge about the inner workings of CMake's property system.

Fortunately, there is another way: The aforementioned limitation only applies when specifying dependencies via filenames. When specifying them as targets, this problem does not occur. The most obvious example is if a library and the executable that depends on it are built from the same source:

```
add_library(foo_lib some_files.cpp)
add_executable(bar_exe more_files.cpp)

target_link_libraries(bar_exe PUBLIC foo_lib)
```

This 'just works'. The correct library will be chosen for each build configuration. Things get a little more complicated if the library and the executable live in different independent projects. In that case the library has to provide a [configure file with an exported target](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/tutorials/Exporting-and-Importing-Targets) in addition to the binary files.

Instead of calling `find_library` to locate the binaries, the dependent executable now just loads that config file and can then use the imported target as if it was a target from the same project.

Many modern libraries already use this approach instead of the classical `find_library` technique (Qt5 is a prominent example). So if you are at liberty to change the CMakeLists of your dependency and you do not need to support very old CMake versions (<2.6), this is probably the way to go.